# How do I get the command prompt do dissapear after starting a program via a batch script?

Tags: windows-xp, batch-file

I have a windows batch file which I run to start a java application. The problem is that I don't want the command prompt output to be visible after the app starts. And not only that,... I don't event want to see it minimised. I don't want it at all. Any ideas?

Cheers!!

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
start/b javaw.exe ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If your program is not a console application, you can use START.EXE in your batch file to actually launch the real app.  The initial console used to launch the batch file will be closed when the batch file ends.

You could actually probably launch the .bat file with start /b too in order to avoid all console windows.